# Count how many times a class has appeared before a specific occurance

Tags: javascript

In my code, when you click on one of the numbered Divs, it will alert the name of the class attached to the div. What I'm unsure of is how can I detect the number of previous occurrences of that class, so that, for example, if I clicked `2` it will alert `myClass(1)` to say it's the second occurrence of it? (assuming `0` would be the first?)

In need of plain vanilla Javascript for this one.

```js
function counter(itemClicked) {
  var theClass = itemClicked.className;
  alert(theClass);
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass" onclick="counter(this)">1</div>
<div class="myClass" onclick="counter(this)">2</div>
<div class="myClass" onclick="counter(this)">3</div>
```

Comment: Are you in control of the HTML? This isn’t really a good idea in isolation because an element can have multiple classes; how are you going to tell which one to use?

Comment: Ah yeah good point. This is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written by Ryan, this is a highly insecure scenario which will break should the element have multiple classes (and possibly for other things too), however, for your example a simple indexOf will work:

```js
function counter(el) {
  let index = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(el.className)).indexOf(el);
  alert(++index);
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass" onclick="counter(this)">1</div>
<div class="myClass" onclick="counter(this)">2</div>
<div class="myClass" onclick="counter(this)">3</div>
```